# C++11 threads: How to start a thread and, separately, check for its completion?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

In C++11 the call

```
my_thread.join();
```

runs the thread and waits for its completion. And I need to, first, run the thread and, later, to wait for its completion. The way it's done, say, in UNIX systems:

```
pthread_create(...)
```

runs a thread, and

```
pthread_join(...)
```

waits for completion. Is this possible with C++11?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the thread is started as soon as you've done constructing the `std::thread` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::thread::join()` does not make thread run. When `std::thread` object constructs with function-object parameters, The thread runs.

For example:

```
std::thread thrd1(doSomething); // Thread starts
// Some codes...
thrd1.join(); // Wait for thread exit
std::thread thrd2; // default constructor
thrd2 = std::thread(doSomething);
// blablabla...
thrd2.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `C++11` threads are in fact (as far as I know) using the systems main threading facility so for a unix-system it will probably utilize posix threads.

A simple example of doing what I think you want to do could be something like:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

 // The function run from the thread i.e. "run the thread" part of your question.
 void things_to_do_in_thread() {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    // This create the thread and call the function
    std::thread my_thread(things_to_do_in_thread);

    //Join with the main thread
    my_thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

You could also give a `lambda-function` to run which would look like this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::thread my_thread([](){
        std::cout << "Hello world" << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    });

    my_thread.join();
}
```

I hope that is what you are asking for and that it will help you familiarize with the `std` thread implementation in `C++11`.